# WSUS/Windows Update Inconsistency

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, wsus, windows-8.1

I have a new WSUS server setup (Windows Server 2012 R2) and I'm using my workstation and a Windows 7 VM for testing. The initial test for my Windows 7 VM worked fine but now I am seeing some major inconsistencies.

On my Windows 8.1 workstation, when I run "check online for updates" it tells me there are 63 important updates available but 50 of them are needed. (see picture)

When I check WSUS, I am seeing that my workstation needs 16 updates (see picture). When I compare the two, the updates that WSUS says I need are the 13 "unchecked" out of the 63 on my local machine when I click to see the details. When I search for the other 50 Microsoft updates in WSUS, I can find them using the search tool but they show as NOT needed in WSUS for my workstation, even though Microsoft Update says I do.(see picture)

I checked with another Windows 8.1 user and got the same result. I've never run into this problem before.

I am scanning for Windows 8.1 and Office updates:
- Critical Updates
- Feature Packs
- Security Updates
- Service Packs
- Update Rollups

What am I missing here? Any thoughts would be appreciated!

[WSUS Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/902M9.png)

[Inconsistency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncRkZ.png)

Comment: Just in case.... https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e4cfa2f5-f46c-44a3-9a21-a82cab833752/updates-needed-but-no-updates-found-on-client?forum=winserverwsus this may be worth a quick look to you (read all the answers).